# How create an ionicPopup.confirm inside an ionicPopup.show?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, popup, preventdefault

Is it possible to create an [`$ionicPopup.confirm()`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/) inside an [`$ionicPopup.show()`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/)?

I want to show a popup about one item, you can edit the item in this popup. There will be also a button to delete that item. I want a confirmation popup.

The problem is that the $ionicPopup.show() is close on tab on the buttons. To avoid that you can use `e.preventDefault()` but then no value is returned to next promise.

The popup is like this:

```
$scope.openPopUp = function(item){
    $scope.popUp = $ionicPopup.show({
        templateUrl: 'templates/popUp.html',
        title: item.title,
        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [
            { /* Cancel button */ }, 
            { /* Save button */ },
            { /* Delete button */ }
        ]
    })
    .then(function(){
        // Save, Delete, etc
    });
};
```

I *achieved* two kind of delete buttons, none perfect.

First. Confirmation is shown. Both *yes* and *no* close confirmation popup but next promise is never executed (save, delete, etc).

```
{
    text: 'Delete',
    type: 'button-block button-light',
    onTap: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: 'Delete',
            template: 'Are you sure you want to delete the item?'
        });
    }
}
```

Second way, not doing `e.preventDefault()` will return the promise, then even when cancel button (no delete) is tap both confirmation and show popups will be closed.

```
{
    text: 'Delete',
    type: 'button-block button-light',
    onTap: function(e) {
        return $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: 'Delete',
            template: 'Are you sure you want to delete the item?'
        })
        .then(function(answer) {
            if (answer) {
                return true;
            } else {
                 e.preventDefault(); // Too late
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way to return a value to next promise but also do not close first popup if cancel button is tap?

Comment: I'll say you're using the wrong components. You should rather use a modal to display and edit the item, then call a popup when you wanna delete.

Comment: I had to change plenty of things but $ionicModal + $ionicPopup.confirm works!